# Https: Blocked by Windows Firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-firewall

We're using Windows 2016 EC2 instance and incoming HTTPS is being dropped, 
Even though the Windows FW Incoming rule is set to allow inbound 443.

Looking at Windows FW logs (of the server) it seems its blocking Incoming traffic:  **2018-10-31 09:54:08 DROP TCP x.x.x.x  172.30.1.110 58837 443 52 S 2608940108 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE**

Only if I change "Inbound Connections" to "Allow" for the "Private Profile" (It's under Advanced Settings > Actions > Properties > State) - then traffic is received.

Is there a proper set up the allows working properly with "Inbound Connections" as  "Blocked (default)"?

BTW: I'm not aware of any rule that is supposed to dominate my rule.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

You might want to look at the security groups settings you have setup in AWS on the instance to see if you are allowing traffic to the Ec2 instance on port 443.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

There is also Network ACL, but most people get caught out by Security groups so I check that first.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html

and lastly you might want to check that your instance has a public ip assigned if you are trying to talk directly to the box from outside of AWS and subnet routing is correctly set for public subnet.

This link might help,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario1.html